# Why would aliens leave Crop Circles?

Tags: aliens

One of the signs of Alien Life visiting Earth has been mysterious crop circles. For argument's sake let us assume that aliens are real and they are leaving these behind.

Crop circles generally appear at night when it's logical to assume there is less activity in the area as humans are recuperating. This would suggest that our space visitors want to do what they want to do on earth (observe us sleeping, relax under our sky, steal shit) when there are less prying eyes.

Assuming this is true, then why would they leave behind evidence where they landed? Why not land somewhere that leaves less evidence like a field not covered in stall stalk of crop like corn or wheat, or even try and hide it by blasting the place so it destroys the crop circle and leaving behind a rock so it looks like a freak meteor strike?

Comment: Aliens might leave crop circles to draw attention to all the nearby [cows they tipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_tipping).

Comment: I would suggest looking at the existing body of speculation on this subject. That's all this topic is at the moment: speculation. There's no "best" answer to this question. Voting to close as _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: Assuming that their technology is more advanced than ours, do we need to assume that those crop circles appear because of landing some vehicle?  They could just use special beams from a long distance to make the crop fall down in their (artistic?) design.

Answer (score 14):

To me, this is classic misdirection.

Let's say you want to investigate humans in (say) Paris. The last thing you want is people **actively** looking for you there. But, humans are a curious lot and after that complete misunderstanding at Roswell, they've learnt that humans are going to be looking for them regardless of what they do.

So; you know they're going to look, so why not give them somewhere to look that's somewhere you're not going to be?

You go into (say) Ireland at night, make some pretty scary crop circles, and haul tail out of there by 3am, giggling to yourself. You then for the next week are pretty free to do your investigations in Paris (the few active UFO hunters there have hauled tail to Ireland to check out the latest evidence) undisturbed.

Quite frankly, if I was a UFO hunter, the last place I'd be looking is where the lights in the sky or the crop circles are. If they're not weather balloons and drunk guys who're bored of tipping cows, they're the aliens saying 'Hey! Look over here!' while they're doing their real work in a different location.

Comment: But what if a competing alienist thinks the same way and sets up weather balloons in Paris while you're busy in Ireland? :)

Comment: If it's that busy, then you'd need some ATC (Alien Traffic Control) to coordinate things. :)

Comment: @TimB And how to keep the ATC hidden? Just [dress them in black suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_black)... and don't forget the snappy [eyewear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black_(1997_film))

Answer (score 5):

It's a cultural thing, you wouldn't get it. Like heart-shaped carvings on a tree, fireworks on new years eve or disks through the lower-lip.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Albeit a bit short, this is an interesting answer. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: So you're saying it's the aliens' version of that weird S shape that we graffiti on everything?

Answer (score 3):

It is an experiment to test how *homo sapiens* reacts to certain input in the environment.

After all, our scientists also change setup of experiments during low activity times and then observe how the subjects, be them apes, mice, bee, humans to say some, interact with the modified set up.

Answer (score 1):

One thought I had is that they are marking locations for future use, eg. after careful calculations, the marked spots might be key locations to setup some processing structures - or pressure points that might be easy locations to split the earth into chunks!

Much like city workers spray paint roads to mark where a hole should be dug for a future plumbing/street work.

Answer (score 0):

There is one interesting use of crop circles in a TV series called *Ben 10 - Alien Force* where the aliens were using crop circles as a sort of circuit boards to make weather machines.

You could say the crop circles are a way of changing the environment in a bigger attempt to terraform the planet, or it could be a weapon that fuses metal to organic matter at high speeds and ends up flattening the crops in weird designs.

Answer (score 0):

**They're searching for something.**

The circles are produced by spot searches for something they believe is buried under the ground and very well camouflaged, such as a ship belonging to an adversary, and the sophisticated sensor package required to detect it produces a variety of gravitational anomalies which as a side-effect, flatten fragile plant material. The patterns are a fingerprint of the complex fractal gravitational interference patterns used in an attempt to bamboozle the sought object's active camouflage.

Comment: If you want to get really conspiracy-theorist crackpot loony about it: the markings aren't random, they are nexus points between the powerful and mysterious ley lines of the planet's magnetic field. This is why stone circles are built over such places; they are simply more permanent versions of the same markings that aliens leave when they make crop circles.

Answer (score 0):

**Transient marking visible from the air.**
Like crop art (art exhibits made by mowing fields in given patterns) crop circles are markings visible from the air but not easily visible or decipherable from the ground. if aliens visit earth it likely to assume they use flying vehicles. a crop circle can be a marking providing guidance or relating information to flying object but their temporary nature provides for a sort of self destroying message. and if you consider that such formations involve marked recessions in the surface (tall stalks vs flattened stalks) it can be possible to detect them by scanning the ground topology with radar or sonar like devices (similar to mapping the ocean floor) therefor eliminating the need to visually inspect the ground which may be problematic in the night.